# Bootstrap select not picking up the selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have two bootstrap select tags, one which has integer values as options and the other one which has strings as options. I have a angular grid, which displays some data which is fetched from a DB. When I select any row in the grid, the select tag should reflect the selected value. The select with integer option works fine, but the select with the string options doesn't change when I select a row in the grid. Below is my code.

HTML :

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="IntegerSelect" title="Choose an 
integer" ng-options="integer.value as integer.label for integer in 
integers"> Integer </select>
<select class="selectpicker" name="StringSelect" title="Choose a string" ng-options="string.value as string.label for string in 
strings"> String </select>
```

JavaScript:

```
('select[name=IntegerSelect]').selectpicker('val',row.entity.Integer);
('select[name=StringSelect]').selectpicker('val',row.entity.String);
```

where Integer and String are the column names in ng-grid.

How do I set the select tag for even strings upon selecting a row in ng-grid?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2

Comment: this question has nothing to do with [angular-ui-bootstrap]

Comment: I tried using <option></option> tags instead of ng-options and it works. I guess combining bootstrap-selectpicker which is a jQuery plugin and ng-options which is a angular directive doesn't work as expected. Or I may be missing the bridge in between. Switching to ui-select which is a cleaner way as suggested.